# Translate in context

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I have a very short partial sentence to translate in context from English to Latin. 
It is for a memorial to my brother.
It is his photo then ... and the ones I have loved.
How can I translate "and the ones I have loved" to Latin?

I have tried numerous sites. In all cases only some of the words are translated.

Comment: What is the context here? That looks like a part of something bigger. You'll get much more helpful translations if you explain what you want to express.

Comment: A memorial to my brother. It is his photo then ... and the ones I have loved

Comment: Thanks! I edited that in. You can always edit your own posts to clarify them; comments can be deleted after a while. I still don't fully understand what you're after here. Is it a photo of him and of the people you have loved? Or is the photo of just him and the others are present? This difference will be visible in Latin. It might be my being slow, but a complete sentence or passage with that phrase would help make grammatical sense of it.

Answer (score 2):

There are various pronouns that you might use for 'those', but I would choose *quisque*, 'each one severally'.

It isn't necessary to use a plural in this compound pronoun : the Latin will mean 'and whomsoever I have loved', not restricted in either number or gender. This produces *et quemque amavi*.

Answer (score 1):

The context is indeed relevant. If you want the memorial to be, in a sense, a list of people, the nominative is appropriate. If you instead are dedicating the memorial **to** the listed people (as is often done), then it is the dative which is appropriate.

Thus, in either case, I would propose something like

> et omnes quos amavi (nominative, masculine)
>
> et omnibus quos amavi (dative)

(both meaning "and [to] all whom I loved"; the second one having the "to")

Notice that for the former example, I have selected the masculine (*qui*) for the general gender of the group (as it is often done in some languages, e.g. Spanish), but you can also select the feminine, *quae* (an issue Tom's answer doesn't need to deal with). The second option above does not have such gender choice.

Additionally, one can say "and [to] all **those** whom I loved", noticing that  "those", like *qui/quae*, is no gender neutral in the nominative. Thus, you would need to pick one: *illi* or *illae* for the masculine and feminine, respectively. The dative is the same, *illis*. Thus, you can have:

> et omnes illi quos amavi (nominative, masculine)
>
> et omnibus illis quos amavi (dative)

Comment: Both qui and quibus should be quos, because the relative pronoun is the direct object of amavi in both instances

Comment: @cnread Thanks for the feedback. Is there a way to rephrase the expression so that the accusative becomes evident? I just fail to see this. I'm not saying you are wrong. I just want to understand it, rather than just making the suggested change, and not understanding why.

Comment: It's just the way relative pronouns work: their case depends on the function that they have in the relative clause itself; it doesn't depend on or have to match the case of the antecedent (omnes/omnibus) – in fact, if it does happen to match the antecedent, that's merely incidental. Think about why, in the English translation that appears after your 2 Latin suggestions, you (correctly) chose to say '**whom** I loved' instead of '**who** I loved' or '**to whom** I loved': it's because the relative pronoun, in English as in Latin, functions as the direct object inside the relative clause.

Comment: @cnread I see. Clear now. Thanks!